# Loading a textfile in python and sorting every word by alphabet as the output of a dictionary:

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Following function is required: A textfile, which needs to be read into Python, and the words have to be sorted by alphabetic order as an output into a dictionary.

A given textfile:

```
Im about to go to the movies on Monday!
And Im very excited to go.
```

Following code reads the file and removes unecessary characters:

```
def movietext():
    with open("movietext.txt", "r") as textfile:
     text = textfile.read()
     for char in "!":
         text=text.replace(char,"")
     return text
print(movietext())
```

Which results in the following:

```
Im about to go to the movies on Monday
And Im very excited to go
```

The requirement from this is to get a dictionary printed out as following:

```
And: 1
about: 1
excited: 1
go: 1
Im: 2
Monday: 1
movies: 1
on: 1
the: 1
to: 3
very: 1
```

Very thankful for any kind of help on solving this.

Comment: Agreed about making an attempt before firing off a SO question. Seems like this could be useful here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize a few of Python's built-in functions, [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
string = '''Im about to go to the movies on Monday
And Im very excited to go'''

words = string.split()
words2 = sorted(set(words))

for key, value in zip(words2, map(words.count, words2)):
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
And: 1
about: 1
excited: 1
go: 1
Im: 2
Monday: 1
movies: 1
on: 1
the: 1
to: 3
very: 1
```

Explanation:

As you know, `words = string.split()` takes the string `string` and stores every substring separated by a space into the list `words`.

The line

```
words2 = sorted(set(words))
```

removes any duplicate words, sorts them, and stores the resulting list into the variable `words2`.

Finally, the line

```
zip(words2, map(words.count, words2))
```

maps every word in the sorted list to the [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method *(where the list is the original list that contains the duplicate words)*, and prints out the counts next to their corresponding word.